# HTML infinite pan-able canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I create an 'infinite' canvas with text boxes dotted around? Like [this one at the Desmos site](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

I have not managed to implement it myself.

Comment: Don't have much experience with canvas, but can you use multiple canvases just like Google Maps uses small map tiles?

Comment: @james-clarke Quite an interesting example you shared. Have you since then figure out how it was built?

Answer (score 18):

The simplest approach to a pan-able canvas is to draw everything relative to an offset, in this example I have called this panX & panY. Imagine it as a coordinate you use to move the viewport (the area of the infinite board that is currently visible in the canvas).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
   
   var imageWidth = 180;
   var imageHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var bounds = null;
   var selectedBox = null;
   var panX = 0;
   var panY = 0;
   var mouseX = 0;
   var mouseY = 0;
   var oldMouseX = 0;
   var oldMouseY = 0;
   var mouseHeld = false;
   var boxArray = [];
   
   function DraggableBox(x,y,width,height,text) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.text = text;
    this.isSelected = false;
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.isCollidingWidthPoint = function(x,y) {
    return (x > this.x && x < this.x + this.width)
     && (y > this.y && y < this.y + this.height);
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.drag = function(newX,newY) {
    this.x = newX - this.width * 0.5;
    this.y = newY - this.height * 0.5;
   }
   
   DraggableBox.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.isSelected) {
     ctx.fillStyle = "darkcyan";
     ctx.fillRect(
      this.x - panX,
      this.y - panY,
      this.width,
      this.height
     );
     ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    } else {   
     ctx.fillRect(
      this.x - panX,
      this.y - panY,
      this.width,
      this.height
     );
    }
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(
     this.text,
     this.x + this.width * 0.5 - panX,
     this.y + this.height * 0.5 - panY,
     this.width
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   }
   
   window.onmousedown = function(e) {
    mouseHeld = true;
   
    if (!selectedBox) {
     for (var i = boxArray.length - 1; i > -1; --i) {
      if (boxArray[i].isCollidingWidthPoint(mouseX + panX,mouseY + panY)) {
       selectedBox = boxArray[i];
       selectedBox.isSelected = true;
       requestAnimationFrame(draw);
       return;
      }
     }
    }
   }
   
   window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - bounds.left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
    
    if (mouseHeld) {
     if (!selectedBox) {
      panX += oldMouseX - mouseX;
      panY += oldMouseY - mouseY;
     } else {
      selectedBox.x = mouseX - selectedBox.width * 0.5 + panX;
      selectedBox.y = mouseY - selectedBox.height * 0.5 + panY;
     }
    }
    
    oldMouseX = mouseX;
    oldMouseY = mouseY;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   }
   
   window.onmouseup = function(e) {
    mouseHeld = false;
    
    if (selectedBox) {
     selectedBox.isSelected = false;
     selectedBox = null;
     requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
   }
   
   function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,imageWidth,imageHeight);
    
    var box = null;
    var xMin = 0;
    var xMax = 0;
    var yMin = 0;
    var yMax = 0;
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    
    for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; ++i) {
     box = boxArray[i];
     
     xMin = box.x - panX;
     xMax = box.x + box.width - panX;
     yMin = box.y - panY;
     yMax = box.y + box.height - panY;
     
     if (xMax > 0 && xMin < imageWidth && yMax > 0 && yMin < imageHeight) {
      box.draw();
     }
    }
   }
   
   window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = imageWidth;
    canvas.height = imageHeight;
    
    bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.font = "15px Arial"
    
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,25,"This is a draggable text box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"Another text box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"Text in a box"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,100,50,"I find this box quite texing"));
    boxArray.push(new DraggableBox(Math.random() * 320,Math.random() * 240,150,50,"You weren't supposed to find this box"));
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
   }
   
   window.onunload = function() {
    canvas = null;
    ctx = null;
    bounds = null;
    selectedBox = null;
    boxArray = null;
   }
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```